# Angular type script dependencies undefined or class not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I want to to inject a injectable in a injectable that extends an abstract class. But either my dependencies are undefined or the class itself is undefined. The class was working fine before I added the stepRouter so I am assuming it is an issue with that class somewhere.

I first had an issue where my dependencies were undefined and stumble on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5155 and saw I had to class super as well. But when calling super the class itself went undefined.

**note: I removed all the content off the classes and just left any constructors and decorators**

**The error: ReferenceError: InstallationWizard is not defined**

The class I am trying to use.

If I remove the constructor from this class the error is gone but all the properties will be undefined.

```js
@Injectable()
export class InstallationWizard extends Wizard {
    constructor(
        protected storage: Storage,
        protected toaster: Toaster,
        protected projectApi: ProjectApi,
        protected formApi: FormApi,
        public stepRouter: InstallationStepRouter
    ) {
        super(storage, toaster, projectApi, formApi, stepRouter)
    }
}
```

The abstract Wizard class

```js
export abstract class Wizard {
    constructor(
        protected storage: Storage,
        protected toaster: Toaster,
        protected projectApi: ProjectApi,
        protected formApi: FormApi,
        public stepRouter: StepRouter
    ) {
        this.pictures = new Array<PictureInterface>();
    }
}
```

The installation step router

```js
@Injectable()
export class InstallationStepRouter extends StepRouter {

}
```

The abstract class it is extending

```js
export abstract class StepRouter {
}
```

Comment: the class Wizard should be declared as injectable

Comment: How did you add the InstallationWizard service to module or component?

Comment: @Ricardo Does not seem to work, still getting Uncaught ReferenceError: InstallationWizard is not defined.

Comment: @MoslemShahsavan I added it to app.modules.ts as a provider

Comment: try @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

Comment: @Ricardo Just in the abstract Wizard class or in all the injectable decorators?

Comment: by using this you don't need to declared it in a module, I will say the abstract class

Comment: @Ricardo Hmm seems like I can't pass any arguments to Injectable. ```Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.```. I am importing injectable form @angular/core, is this correct? My angular version is 4.1.2

Comment: @Qamie see example https://stackblitz.com/edit/class-inheritance?embed=1&file=src/app/services.ts

Answer (score 0):

Use @angular/core Injector

```
@Injectable()
export class InstallationWizard extends Wizard {
    constructor(
        protected injector: Injector
    ) {
        super(injector)
    }
}

export abstract class Wizard {
    protected stepRouter: StepRouter;

    constructor(injector: Injector
    ) {
        this.stepRouter = this.injector.get(StepRouter);
    }
}
```